# Break lines in multicolumn in a table

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx, multicolumn

In the following,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{array,ltablex,graphicx,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=0.500cm, bottom=2.50cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{BDD6EE}

\author{Andrea Croci}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{{\Large \textbf{Messwertetabelle}} \newline Trage die Zeiten ein}\\
            \hline
            Masse & \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{Masse des Wagens  \underline{\phantom{Masse des Wagens}} g} & \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{Masse des Wagens  \underline{\phantom{Masse des Wagens}} g} & \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{Masse des Wagens \underline{\phantom{Masse des Wagens}} g}\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

the `\newline` in the `\multicolumn` gets ignored an I've tried several different solutions, but none of them has worked. I also would like the underscores to be in a separate line. I tried with a `p{}` (or similar) column type in `\multicolumn` but then I have to enter the width manually and I would like to have it automatically calculated like in the `X` columns.

How can one break lines in a `\multicolumn` cell?

Comment: Hmmm... two lines? `\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{first line}\\ \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Second line}\\ `?

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load `xcolor` and `colortbl` independently if you want to maximize the interoperability of the package. Thus, replace `\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}` with`\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`, as is also explained in the user guide of the `xcolor` package.

Comment: @Mico May be off-topic, but thank you very much nonetheless for the suggestion. Not only one has to rtfm, but he has to do it thoroughly too. :-) And while we are there, I also guess I don't need all of the `array`, `ltablex` and `tabularx`. Probably one would suffice?

Comment: @Rmano That would certainly work. Isn't there another way? Just breaking lines inside the one cell?

Comment: Why do you use 7 columns for a table that apparently only consists of 4 columns?

Comment: If you add the `makecell` package to your preamble, you can use `\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\makecell{\Large \bfseries Messwertetabelle \\ Trage die Zeiten ein}}\\ `.

Comment: `array` is already loaded by `tabularx`, so there is no need to load it yourself. Combining `tabularx` with `ltablex` is used if you want a `tabularx` environment to span multiple pages. If you don't want that, you don't need `ltablex`. (Yet another alternative for multiple-page tables that adapt to an overall width would be the `xltabular` package.)

Comment: @leandriis I use 7 columns because my MWE is not a MWE: it's a thing I stripped down from an existing source that needs 7 columns. Thanks for the advice on `array`, etc. However I noticed that if I don't load `ltablex` my table suddenly goes past the right edge of the page, although it's not spanning multiple pages. Funny side effect, probably.

Comment: the standard tabularx is like tabular, so not loading ltablex would have that effect (but xltabular is a better lontable/tabularx merge)  the line break issue is unrelated to tabularx you have specified `c` in the multicolumn and `c` entries are always single line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought so, and that's why I tried with a `p{...}` too. That has the disadvantage that I have to specify a width for the column. I also tried with `X`, which fixes the column's width issue, but that doesn't allow me to break the lines either.

Comment: Why don't you use  `p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}`?

Comment: X is just p{...} with a guessed value of ...  so allows the same line breaking as p but better to do as Bernard comments

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I must be doing something else wrong, because `\multicolumn{2}{|p{4cm}|}{Masse des Wagens \newline whatever}` breaks the line, whereas `\multicolumn{2}{|X|}{Masse des Wagens \newline whatever}` doesn't. I'll give Bernard's suggestion a try.

Comment: oh sorry ltablex breaks this unless you use \keeptabularxcolumns or some such name or use the original tabular or xltabular

Comment: I ended up using a hybrid version of leandriis' suggestion to use `\makecell` with the normal linebreak (\\\) and the gaped cells from the answer below. It looks the way I want, but I'm sure there would be an easier way. I'd love to give `xltabular` a try, but not now: I don't want to have to redo the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Considering comments to your question I suggest you the following solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{BDD6EE}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[hmargin={2cm, 3cm}, 
            vmargin={0.5cm,2.5cm}, 
            includefoot]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{|c|}{#2}}

\author{Andrea Croci}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \centering
        \renewcommand\theadfont{\Large\bfseries}
        \setcellgapes{5pt}
        \makegapedcells
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|X|}
            \hline
            \mcc[4]{\thead{Messwertetabelle\\ 
                           \normalfont
                           Trage die Zeiten ein}}     \\
            \hline
            Masse & Masse des Wagens  \hrulefill\  g
                        & Masse des Wagens  \hrulefill\  g
                            & Masse des Wagens \hrulefill\  g\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, instead of `\underline` are used `\hrulefill`, for additional vertical space is employed macro `makegapedcells` (defined in `makecell` package).

[image]

**Addendum:**
As can be understood from OP comment, the desired formatting of his table is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{BDD6EE}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[hmargin={2cm, 3cm},
            vmargin={0.5cm,2.5cm},
            includefoot]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{|c|}{#2}}

\author{Andrea Croci}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \centering
        \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
        \setcellgapes{5pt}
        \makegapedcells
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|X|}
            \hline
            \mcc[4]{\thead{\Large Messwertetabelle\\
                           \normalfont
                           Trage die Zeiten ein}}     \\
            \hline
            Masse & Masse des Wagens  \hrulefill\  g
                        & Masse des Wagens  \hrulefill\  g
                            & Masse des Wagens \hrulefill\  g\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, although a little complicated for my basic knowledge. Now, why does "Trage die Zeiten ein" look bigger than "Masse"? Is it because the first is in a header?

Comment: @Andyc: This is due to `\renewcommand\theadfont{\Large\bfseries}` with which the font size is set to large. If you want the same fonts size as in the rest of the table, you can use `\thead{Messwertetabelle\\   \normalfont\normalsize Trage die Zeiten ein}` in order to switch back to `\normalsize`.

Comment: @Andyc, from your MWE  follows, that you like to have equal font size, i.e. `\Large` size, for all text in the multi column cell. If this is not a cese, see second solution added to my answer.

Comment: Oh, ok, I got it.